# How can I combine an image slider with scaling images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of a dilemma in the sense that I can't seem to get a jquery image cycler working with scaling images.

What I basically have is a website with a small navigation list at the top, and then full screen images which can be cycled using a control at the bottom of the page. Previously I've used [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) to get the desired effect for a background image that stretches with the browser window.

I was also hoping on using [Jquery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) as the plugin to do the image slider (as I've used this countless times before).

The problem is that I need the effect of backstretch (ie. scaling images) but with a slider. I have tried using other plugins for the stretching but most of them only seem to allow the images to be scaled down (if the window shrinks) rather than upwards. I can't use backstretch because it takes up the entire body tag. I only need a container div to contain the stretched images (so I can have the header/navigation sitting at the top without cropping the images).

However I have no idea how to then get this to work with Jquery Cycle.

Has anyone done this before or have any examples of this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be late but take a look at http://jongaulin.com/2011/11/17/fullscreen-image-and-content-slider/. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually found a solution in the end by writing some js that'd resize the elements dynamically. Maybe your answer could be of some use to someone else though :-)